# Compare 2 csv files with the same header and output a third csv with some calculations

Tags: python, csv, compare

I want to compare 2 csv files and store the results in a new csv file.

I have 2 csv (old.csv and new.csv) with the same headers.

How can I compare the values of each and do calculations based on those?

```
with open('new.csv') as new_csv, open('old.csv') as old_csv:
    reader_old = csv.DictReader(old_csv)
    reader_new = csv.DictReader(new_csv)
    for row_o in reader_old:
        for row_n in reader_new:

            if row_n['Account'] == row_o['Account']:
                amt_diff = float(row_n['Number']) - float(row_o['Number'])
                print(amt_diff)
```

Comment: You can use pandas for it. If you put a small sample of the csv you can get an answer using pandas

Answer (score 0):

Python has [a module called `csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) that will let you do all sorts of reading and writing of csv files, without having to go through the tedious task of manually writing lines to take strings, breaking them up along commas, etc..  For example, you can use `csv.DictReader()` to read lines into a dictionary where the keys are the same as your column names:

```
import csv
with open('new.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        ranking = row['Ranking']
        percentage = row['Percentage']
        print("The percentage in this row is", percentage)
```

After extracting what you need and doing the calculations, you can use `csv.DictWriter` to write data to your new, third csv file.  A search on the web for `python csv module` should give you a number of examples.

**EDIT**: I read your comment and saw your updated code. Let's look at what your nested loop does, as far as I can tell:

1. Take the first line of the old CSV data
2. Take the first line of the new CSV data
3. Compare their values for "Account".  If they're the same, then print their difference (which should be zero if the two numbers are the same, right?)
4. Do the same with line **#1** of the old and line #2 of the new.
5. Do the same with line **#1** of the old and line #3 of the new.
6. Continue until you compare line #1 of the old and the last line of the new.
7. Repeat all of the above with line **#2** of the old and line #1 of the new, then line #2 of the old and line #2 of the new, line #2 of the old and line #3 of the new, etc.

Is that what you want?  Or are you just trying to compare them line by line and write the differences?

EDIT #2:

I don't know if this will make a difference, but try this instead:

```
reader_old = csv.DictReader(open("old.csv"))
reader_new = csv.DictReader(open("new.csv"))
for row_o in reader_old:
    for row_n in reader_new:
        amt_diff = float(row_n['Number']) - float(row_o['Number'])
        print(amt_diff)
```

If you want to write this to a new file instead of just printing the results, see `csv.DictWriter()`.

Comment: Hey Bill, thank you for your answer. I'm familiar with the csv module, I updated and simplified the original answer. The nested for loop isn't really working in this case, but I'm doing something wrong for sure.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, not just the differences. 
The problem is that with the code above it stops the iteration at the first line.